# Change filename according to what user clicks

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, header

I have three files being uploaded into the database by the user once they compete the form.. The problem is that I have 3 different download scripts to retrieve the files... The files are going into database as `fileName1, fileName2, fileName3 and File1, File2, File3`. Is there any way to have only 1 download script instead of 3 different ones?

Here is relevant code:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT FileName3, File3 " .
         "FROM UserUploads WHERE ID = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($filename3, $file3) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename3");
echo $file3;
```

I can add all `fileName1, fileName2, fileName3 and File1, File2, File3` into the `SELECT` statement but the problem is the `header()` and `echo` line after... How can I change that according to what the user clicks?

Comment: First of all: Do you know SQL-Injection? Your code is bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide 3 download links for one user. Each link has a parameter for example 'file':

```
http://your-domain.com/download.php?file=1&id=1234
http://your-domain.com/download.php?file=2&id=1234
http://your-domain.com/download.php?file=3&id=1234
```

Than add a switch case block to your file.

```
$id    = (int)$_GET['id'];
$file  = (int)$_GET['file'];

if($file <= 0 || $file >= 4) {
    die('bad boy');
}

$query = "SELECT FileName$file as filename, File$file as file " .
         "FROM UserUploads WHERE ID = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($fn, $data) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fn");
echo $data;
```

Didn't test it.